# Formula field image not visible from communities

Tags: community, image-formula

I have a formula field displaying an image.  It works great for an internal user but does not work for my partner community.

I have tried using the `IMAGE(LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))++"resource/.` image suggested in another thread but the ++ errors and without that it saves but does not display the image.  Here is my formula

```
CASE( TEXT(Status__c) , 
"Active",  IMAGE("/resource/AccessGranted", "Granted"),
"Revoked",  IMAGE("/resource/AccessRevoked", "Revoked"),
"Expired",  IMAGE("/resource/AccessExpired", "Expired"),
"")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does your community include a path prefix (i.e. community.force.com/prefix)?

Comment: Is the image you are trying to show public?

Comment: could anyone still assist with this please? Our community does have a prefix, and I'm trying to update the images as in the scenario here and the suggested fix is not working. The images display fine from static resources in standard SF but not in the community. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

"LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))+" should have been added to the normal "/resource/..."

Comment: To summarize, you're saying, only a single `+` should be in the first formula as opposed to using the two plusses (`++`). It was the two plusses that caused the errors which preventing it from saving and a single plus sign would have worked?

Comment: Thomas, answers are usually better received if you also explain them.